# Fatal error in creating function that calculates recursively the factorial in php?

Tags: php, recursion

this is the Question i have in my homework.

Using PHP, implement a function that calculates recursively the factorial of a given number below 100.The function should return 0, in case the passed value exceeds 100

and here my answer

```
<?php

function factorial($number)
{ 
    if ($number >= 100) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $number * factorial($number - 1);      
}

print factorial(11); 
?>
```

but the problem when i run the code this  i have Fatal error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 20

this is the line 20 `return $number * factorial($number - 1);`

i think the problem i have is infinite loop :(

and i can't end this loop

Comment: It subtracts one each iteration, but when should that stop? When `$number` is 1? 0? Currently it will never stop, continuing toward negative infinity.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function factorial($number)
{ 
   if ($number >= 100) {
       return 0;
   }
   if($number<= 1){
       return 1;
   }


   return $number * factorial($number - 1);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
<?

function factorial($number)
{ 
if ($number >= 100) {
   return 0;
 }
 elseif($number<= 1){
   return 1; 
 }
 else{/* do nothing */  return $number * factorial($number - 1);  }

 }


 print factorial(11); 


 ?>
```